# How to resolve this : Execution of batch script terminates after a specific command but runs fine when commandd is executed manually

Tags: batch-file, jmeter, command-prompt

I have a requirement to run commands in the following order to automate the testing process:

```
cd "jakarta-jmeter-2.5.1\bin"
jmeter -n -t  "Cmd-Try-Shared-AQ.jmx" -l log.jtl -Jthreads=10
cd "../lib/ext"
java -jar JMeterPluginsCMD.jar --generate-csv test.csv --input-jtl log.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

After executing the JMeter command batch file terminates and does not process next command that is changing the current directory. I tried to troubleshoot by placing PAUSE to see if it reaches the next line but of no help, it simply terminates after executing the second command. If execute the same 4 commands manually one after the other they all execute fine.

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use "call jmeter -n -t ..." since it is another cmd file and Command Prompt requires calls.

Answer (score 4):

Andrey is right -- if jmeter is a batch file you must use "call".  The reason is that if you call a batch file from another, the first one will exit after executing the 2nd one, unless it is called with "call".

Here's an example:

**Foo1.bat**

```
foo2.bat
echo foo1
```

**Foo2.bat**

```
echo foo2
```

It seems like if you run Foo1.bat, it will spit out both "foo1" and "foo2" but it does not:

```
C:\temp>foo1

C:\temp>foo2.bat

C:\temp>echo foo2
foo2
```

To change the behavior, Foo1.bat should look like this:

**foo1.bat**

```
    call foo2.bat
    echo foo1
```

Comment: If a Batch file is executed from another one via its name alone, the result es equivalent to a "goto to another file": when the second Batch file ends the whole execution ends. I call _Overlay_ a Batch file executed this way, instead of _Subroutine_ that was executed via `call`.